# How to display first tab by default in css?

Tags: css

I have `css` based tab menu its working fine for me but by default it is not displaying first tab i want my first tab to be active by default

here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5452wxfy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new CSS for the elements with class `display`:

I gave the `<a>` an `id = "no"` in `tab1`

```
<li id="item-1"> <a  href="#item-1">Tab 1</a>
      <div class="display" id ="no">
        <p>Tab Content 1</p>
          <p>Tab Content 1</p>
          <p>Tab Content 1</p>
      </div>
</li>
```

Then added an `id = "remove1prop"` to `<a>` of `tab2` and `tab3`

```
<li id="item-2"> <a id = "remove1prop" href="#item-2">Tab 2</a>
   <div>
     <p>Tab Content 2</p>
   </div>
</li>
<li id="item-3"> <a id ="remove1prop" href="#item-3">Tab 3</a>
   <div>
     <p>Tab Content 3</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

Wrapped all your tabs in a div with `id = "test"`

Then added the following javascript:

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var elem = document.getElementById("no");
elem.style.display = "block";
function whatClicked(evt) {
    if(evt.target.id == "remove1prop")
        elem.style.display="none";
    else
        elem.style.display="block";
}
test.addEventListener("click", whatClicked, false);
```

***NOTE: Remove the css I had given you before from the css style sheet***

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/5452wxfy/6/

Comment: i want first tab to be visible but after selecting second tab first tab must be display none right now it isnt http://jsfiddle.net/5452wxfy/5/

Comment: @AtifAzad wait what? cant understand your question clearly . Pls explain :)

Comment: @AtifAzad you want all those tab1 to change with click?

Comment: it is fine first tab is displaying now but the problem is that when you select second tab or third tab first tab still remain visible :(

Comment: @AtifAzad oh you will need javascript for that , but let me try it with css

Comment: @AtifAzad hmm , not possible with css can i provide u with a javscript solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece:

```
.css-tabs ul.menu li > div.display {
    display: block;
}
```

After:

```
.css-tabs ul.menu li > div {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    margin:-1px 0 0 0;
    z-index:-1;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5452wxfy/2/

Comment: it is not hiding when selecting tab2

Comment: I already updated the fiddle without js, see my latest changes